# Cannot write a file outside of app root in PHP under Apache, Linux, cPanel

Tags: php, apache

I have full access to my server. I have set up the cPanel/Apache configuration to allow access to directory /var/web/reuse (which is not under my document root), but I cannot create or write files there in PHP. I can read files there using PHP. The basedir is none, according to phpinfo. I am able to write files in my document root dir and descendants with no problem. The directory in which I am trying to write has Linux permissions drwxrwxrwx. I am writing using a full absolute pathname. PHP function is_writeable() returns false for the file's parent dir.

Added 10/15/18:

permissions are as follows:

```
/ dr-xr-xr-x
/var drwxr-xr-x
/var/web drwxr-xr-x
/var/web/reuse drwxr-xr-x
/var/web/reuse/data drwxrwxrwx (I am trying to write here)
```

Any suggestions based on this description?

Comment: Show the file ownership. In Unbuntu, for example, the group should usually be www-data and frequently the owner is too.

Try chmod -r www-data:www-data <dir name>

Comment: Sorry, the owner is root and I am writing as another user. Doesn't rwx for user allow this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your entire path. Probably you've some parent directory without access permission.

Also, you can run a simple script to check the PHP error message:

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL);
ini_set ( "display_errors", "on");
file_put_contents ( "/var/web/reuse/test.txt", "hello world!");
?>
```

You maybe been blocked by [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) PHP directive.

At console, you can check your directory tree permissions using:

```
ls -lad /var
ls -lad /var/web
ls -lad /var/web/reuse
```

Also, you can check which user PHP is using running this script:

```
<?php
$userinfo = posix_getpwuid ( posix_getuid ());
var_dump ( $userinfo);
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code first, although I am suspecting a permissions problem. Do I really have to give x permission to all parent directories? Sounds insecure.

Here is the output of the test:

Warning: file_put_contents(/var/web/reuse/test.txt): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /home/nsr/public_html/Tests/Protect/index.php on line 8

Comment: No, you don't need to give 777 (+rwx) permissions to all parent directories, it's really insecure. Your PHP user need to have execution access (+x) to access a sub directory. Your problem are described at the PHP error message (that's why I enabled all errors). Your directory /var/web/reuse are in READ ONLY filesystem. Check if your disk are Read Only mounted (use the command **mount** as *root* and check if there's a *ro* flag to your partition.

Comment: Mount gave me a long list. I don't know what I'm looking for. Most of the entries start with "/home/virtfs/",

Comment: Please use an easier command. Just go to "/var/web/reuse" directory and use the command "findmnt -T .". Look at *OPTIONS* tab if there's any *ro* (read only) flag.

Comment: The result is "TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda1 ext3   rw,relatime,data=ordered"

Comment: Your file system are read write. Another problem could be SELinux permission if you're using a RHEL/CentOS based distribution. Please run "setenforce 0" as *root* and try the script again. If it's not a production environment, you can disable SELinux to do tests. You can refer to SELinux here: https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/

Comment: Stack overflow is asking me to move this discussion to chat. Should I do this? I am running with SELinux disabled.

Comment: I will ask my hosting company for help and report back here. There must be a solution.